# Mask numpy array based on pandas conditional

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have an array of x and y values (same length)

```py
x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8])
y = np.array([3, 4, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 10, 6, 4, 2, 3, 1, 8, 3, 1, 6, 4])
```

I have a separate dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [0.3, 1.1], 'Duration': [0.2, 0.4]})
```

I want to zero the values of `y` where corresponding indexes of `x` fall between `df['Time'][i] <= x < df['Time'][i] + df['Duration'][i]` (for any `i`) yielding the following:

```py
y_out = np.array([3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 10, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 6, 4])
```

Note: I have to do this on millions of points, so it has to be relatively fast...

Comment: Where is `i` going to come from? Is it just a constant?

Comment: `i` is the index of the `df` row, so each point should be compared every row in the `df` to see whether it should be zeroed

Comment: Interesting problem.

Comment: Is array `x`/`df` sorted?

Comment: @AndrejKesely both are sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.greater_equal`'s `outer` function to make this vectorized.

```
mask = (np.greater_equal.outer(x, df['Time'].to_numpy()) 
        & np.less.outer(x, (df['Time'] + df['Duration']).to_numpy())).any(1)
```

Then simply

```
 y[mask] = 0
```

---

Using the outer product means that you will, in a vectorized way, compare all values of your array `x` with all values of your rows in `df`. This is fast, but costly in terms of memory.

Consider partitioning the processing in chunks, in case the whole operation doesn't fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would use logical operations + `np.multiply` and then map like this:

```py
np.multiply(y, ((x < record['Time']) | (x > record['Time'] + record['Duration'])))
```

here is a working example: https://abstra.show/4qgrdKVzLP

reference:

- [np.multiply](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)
- [logical or](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)